# RxJS Is there a way to make ajax get request with params without building url

Tags: redux-observable

I am having trouble passing params to ajax get request.
Let's suppose i have to pass params `{category: 'cat', type: 'type', searchKey: 'key' }` to the url `/search` and I have the code below:

```
action$.ofType('QUERY')
    .debounceTime(500)
    .switchMap(action =>
      ajax.get('/search', {//pass some parameters},)
        .map(result => ({
          type: 'FETCH_SUCCESS',
          payload: result.response,
        })),
```

As I am new to RxJs, Please suggest me the right way of doing this.

Comment: I'm not quite sure, where you having troubles. Since you get the current `action` from the `switchMap()` callback, you can just access the payload of your action. Also, is `ajax` = `Observable.ajax`?

Comment: yes, i can get payload from action and i am passing that object like this `ajax.get('/search', action.payload)` this requests the url '/search' but parameters are not sent with the request. and yes ajax = Obserable.ajax

Comment: The second argument of `Observable.ajax.get` is for defining `headers`. Only the first argument is for the URL. If the your payload are query parameters, you need to serialize them accordingly.

Comment: yeah thank you for explanation. right now i am doing it in similar way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While it is technically permissible to provide a request body (and corresponding `Content-Type` header like `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`) for `GET` requests, nearly all servers assume `GET` do not contain one. Instead, `POST` (creation of a document) or `PUT` (updating a document) is used when a body is neccesary.

However, if what you're asking for is simply regular old query params, that's pretty normal but there is no built-in support in RxJS for converting an Object to a query string--mostly because there is no official spec on how complex objects/arrays should be serialized so every server has notable differences once you do more than simple key -> value.

Instead, you just include them in the URL. I realize you said "without building url" but the lack of a spec means RxJS will likely never add support because it's highly opinionated. You can just manually generate the string yourself or use a third-party utility that has a convention you like.

```
ajax.get(`/search?query=${query}&something=${something`)

// or using something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/query-string

ajax.get(`/search?${queryString.stringify(params)}`)
```

---

If you're interested in further understanding the opinionated nature of query params, consider how you might serialize `{ foo: [{ bar: 1 }, { bar: 2 }] }`. Some might say it should be `?foo[0][bar]=1&foo[1][bar]=2` but I have also seen `?foo[][bar]=1&foo[][bar]=2`, `?foo[bar]=1&foo[bar]=2`, and other variants. Thing get even more hairy when dealing with duplicates. `?foo=true&foo=false` should `foo` be true or false? (it's an opinion hehe)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. @jayphelps

Comment: @duwalansise you're very welcome! If this solved your question, consider marking it as accepted 